# Rotational motion and Circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, rotational-kinematics

What is the difference between rotational motion and circular motion?  Are they same or they different?

Comment: Circular motion: https://www.physicskey.com/10/circular-motion, rotational motion: https://www.physicskey.com/21/rotational-motion

Answer (score 3):

"Circular motion" usually refers to a point mass (or an object small enough to be considered a point mass) moving along a circular trajectory.  An example would be a ball being swung around at the end of a rope.

"Rotational motion" usually refers to a larger body changing its orientation in space.  An example would be a wheel turning on a fixed axis, or the tumbling of an object as it falls freely.  If the axis of the rotation is fixed, then every particle in the body is in circular motion, since every point moves along a circular path.

Comment: Is it necessary to have pivoted body for rotatory motion

Answer (score 0):

Circular motion in itself is the motion of a point mass in a circle.

When we look at rotational motion though, things get quite interesting.
Rotational motion is the motion of a rigid body as a whole such that the particles(a rigid body is actually a collection of numerous point particles) of the rigid body execute circular motion around a line which may or may not pass through the rigid body.
We call this line the axis of rotation.

An interesting observation is that say, we have an object rotating such that the axis of rotation passes through it, ( for example, take a globe model which is pivoted using its stand ) then each particle that lies on the axis of rotation doesn't move at all! while all other particles perform circular motion around the axis.

Answer (score 0):

**Rotational motion**
This means that an object is *rotating* around its own axis. It doesn't move from one point to another.
Eg., a spinning top is spinning around its own axis. It is exhibiting rotational motion.

**Circular motion**
This is concerned with an object *moving* in a circular path. Its position changes with time.
Eg., Ram moves around the boundary of his circular garden. He is exhibiting circular motion.

Hope you benefit from my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Circular motion : a point particle moving in a circular path.

Rotational motion : for a **system of particles** , whole system doing circular motion absolutely or with respect to frame attached to axis.